# Adding Values to Model Array Object from Adapter

Tags: java, android, arraylist, android-adapter

I have a `Specialty[]` array that is an object of a model class in my adapter. I want to clear the `Specialty[]` array before adding new values. For that purpose re-initialize it. When trying to add a new value I am getting index out of range. Is there any way we can increase the size of the model object? Thanks. 
Here is my code:

```
  //reinitializing 
  mgm = new Specialties []{};
  mgm[0].setName("abc");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You can use `java.util.Arrays.copyOf(...)` to resize
- Or Replace by `ArrayList`
- Or Before add new value, `reinitial mgm = new Specialties [1];`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you got that issue. Because you cannot change your `Array` size after initializing it.

```
 mgm = new Specialties []{};  -> you create an Array with size = 0. You cannot change it later.
```

I guess that you should use `ArrayList` instead.